# Powerbi desktop can't connect to postgres but psql can

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I cant connect to postgres server with this error message:

> Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'"

But I can connect via psql. What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: ODBC work perfect too. What happen with Postgress connect?

Comment: From the text of the message, it looks like your didn't specify the port on which the server is listening.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov The port is 5432. Same problem with Looker studio when I try to connect via public ip address